# 'N' in Crystal reports sql query where clause

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports-2010

Can anybody tell me what the **N** is at the beginning of value in WHERE clause from Crystal Reports show SQL Query is doing (example below)?  When I plug in as is into Sql Server, the query returns much slower because it appears to be initially going through way more records than it needs.  When I removed the **N**, I get much faster results, and it doesn't seem to be hitting as many records.  Is there a way to prevent Crystal from adding this when running reports?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example: ...WHERE  "usr_MasterBill"."car_move_id"=**N**'M090036749'

Answer (score 1):

It uses 16 bytes for each character, allowing unicode strings to be created.  This kind of string should be assigned to nvarchar, nchar, ntext etc. data types.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/write-differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the **N** in the query, but how CR works, in some cases the CR Core decides that is better retrieves all registers and filter on presentation load. 
Verify the "Select expert" for additional filters, or in change group options "Specified Order". You need check to the formulas fields